# Yii: errorSummary in formBuilder

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

How do I use errorSummary in my view, if the form is built using formBuilder?

I tried

```
echo $form -> errorSummary();
```

but it doesn't work.

Can it actually be used with formBuilder?

**EDIT:**

The form:

```
return array(
'activeForm' => array(
    'class' => 'CActiveForm',
    'id' => 'nameserver-form',
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
),
'showErrorSummary'=>true,
'showErrors'=>true,
'elements'=>array(
    'ip1_address'=>array(
        'type'=>'dropdownlist',
        'empty'=>''
    ),
    'ns1_nameserver'=>array(
        'type'=>'text',
        'maxlength'=>255,
        'size'=>25
    )
)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer was:

```
<?= $form->renderBegin(); ?>   
... 
<?= $form->activeFormWidget->errorSummary($form->getModel(false)); ?>
...
<?= $form->renderEnd(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

this function required a parameter that is not provided in your code.like :

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
   'id'=>'user-form',
   'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
   'enableClientValidation'=>true,
   'focus'=>array($model,'firstName'),
)); ?>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#errorSummary-detail

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is, this is not my code, and i need to edit it. When trying this i get `FormBuilder and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "errorSummary".`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the class name you mentioned. but if that class was extended from CController, it should be able to do the trick. You might want to look into and trace the FormBuilder class that your app is using

Comment: did you find your answer?